# React.js not connecting to (localhost) Ganache on EC2: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 127.0.0.1:8545

Tags: reactjs, ganache

Using the following installation on Ubuntu Server 20.04 :

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install nodejs 
sudo apt install python2 
sudo apt install npm 
npm install ganache-cli 
npm install node-gyp@3.6.2 
npm install truffle@5.1.39 
sudo npm install create-react-app@3.3.1 -global 
npm install
```

I am having the error
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED   127.0.0.1:8545/:1

I am running ganache with the command line interface:

[image]

I can test the connection via node command prompt

[image]
To which I am able to verify a connection to ganache private blockchain
[image]

Then I try App.js in React

[image]

obtaining the following error:
[image]

I have tried the following:

```
1.) Setting up a proxy under package.json   :    http://127.0.0.1:8545
2.) Trying http://0.0.0.0:8545
3.) Setting up a middleware proxy account as presented in the following solution: 
https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
4.) addressing cache related issues through  rm -r package-lock.json node_modules and npm install updating react.js to latest version 
5.) trying different port: 7545
6.) updating react to latest version on ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - thanks to all who reviewed my problem. - hopefully this will help someone in the same situation. To connect to an ec2 instance with React.js / blockchain dapp you need to follow five steps:
1.) set appropriate security rules (you will need to allow access for an instance to reach your server) I set the following rules in a very liberal fashion since this was only a test:
[image]

2. you need to start ganache with explicit chainId specified and a direct reference to your public domain IPv4 DNS domain e.g (
   http://ec2-54-186-149-26.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)

the command should look as follows: [image]

3.) the same domain mnemonic needs to be specified in metamask (along with an imported account from your ganache server ) It should look as follows:
[image]

4.) React.js also needs to access the domain from EC2 directly (do not use localhost ,even you are running on the server the loopback will not work!  - also do not use a shortcut with or (||) condition as that also produced errors for me ). It should look similar to below:

[image]

5.) your smart contracts also need this domain specified explicitly - so you will also need to edit your truffle-config.js as follows:

[image]

Finally i can read my blockchain via React.js on a test network (ganache) via EC2.
Below is blockchain data presented to screen.

I hope this helps someone out there - this was not found easily.
regards
John D.

[image]